# Android Logcat not working as expected

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, intellij-13

I am trying to debug an application and my logcat is not working as expected. My application is somewhat complex as it includes a number of jar files. I can receive logcat messages from the main application and 2 of the jar plugins, but the other two jar modules show no logcat messages. Is there some 'trick' that I am missing ?

Here is my solution structure.

- Main application is a Unity game. logcat's fine.
- A C NDK bridge plugin. logcat's fine.
- A Java bridge plugin. logcat's fine.

  - A websocket api, logcat does not work.

I am not sure how to proceed. I have tried restarting adb. I have tried System.out.println. I have tried deactivating filters and manually looking for my 'hello world' log's.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**Update**

It is working now. I have no Idea what I did differently. Maybe a reboot.

Comment: Are you sure the code is running, i.e. the code in that source file is being executed (vs. code for the same library being pulled in from a different lib/jar)?  Set a breakpoint or call System.halt() right after one of your logcat messages.

Comment: Yes the code is running. There is a bug in some situations but for the most part the code is working.

Comment: My guess, based on the self-correction, is that the code wasn't getting rebuilt, and you were running an older version that didn't have the logging included.  At some point while fiddling with it the updated code made it to the device.